# MIDI NOTE_ON NOTE_OFF message correspondence

Tags: java, message, midi, overlap

I'm following another tutorial on stack-overflow about printing out all note on/off messages from a midi-file.

Now the problem is, when I have a Note_ON event, how do I know which of the following Note_OFF messages is the corresponding one? Since Notes can overlap and be within one another. I looked through the MIDI Specification but unfortunately found nothing concerning this, and also other sources did not provide any detail.

But this must be possible, since Mathematica prints out the tuples of (Note-Pitch,Start-time,Stop-time).

Answer (score 1):

In theory, every note-on event must have a corresponding note-off event, and notes with the same value must not overlap.

What happens in practice in these cases is not specified.
Therefore, any possible interpretation could be assumed to be correct.

(Most synthesizers (with their default settings) do not really allow overlapping notes, i.e., a note-on message will cancel any previous note(s) with the same channel and value.)

Comment: After performing more research on this I found out Cubase has a weird way of interpreting the Notes (Created in Cubase and opened in Mathematica):
    
Cubase: Note1(0s -> 1.5s) Note2(0.5s -> 1.5s) Note3(2s -> 3.5s) Note4(2.5s -> 4s)
    
Mathematica: Note1(0s -> 1s) Note2(0.5s -> 1s) Note3(2s -> 3.5s) Note4(2.5s -> 4s)
    
Java: (0.0s, on, C2) (0.5s, on, C2) (1.0s, off, C2) (1.5s, off, C2) (2.0s, on, C2) (2.5s, on, C2) (3.5s, off, C2) (4.0s, off, C2)

And when I reimport into Cubase after exporting, it looks exactly like the Mathematica representation. So thanks for clearing things up!